# Drag and drop extract pages from PDF with free / open source software

Tags: gratis, open-source, pdf

some of my colleagues need single pages from within a multi-page PDF document. Using Adobe Acrobat for example, you can go to navigation pane and extract via drag and drop a single page to file explorer. PDF XChange Editor can do the same.

Both are paid software, but is there a (Windows) software as freeware / open source which can do that?

I know that there are tools like PDFSam or PDF24 which can do that in a different menu option, but not via drag and drop in Navigation pane. Also, using an external website is also not an option (data security).

There are some colleagues who want it as easy as possible.

I didn't find any other software that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the approaches below might help:

1. Print only the pages you want into the Microsoft PDF printer. This will work with ANY PDF reader, even the common chromium based browsers (edge, chrome).
   This isn't drag-n-drop, but it is built in and 'free'.
2. Use the awesome [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com) for image based PDF authoring tasks (and scanning), it's [FOSS](https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2/blob/master/LICENSE), specifically GPLv2.

   - Drag the PDF into NAPS2
   - Choose the pages you want to keep
   - Save the selected as a new document

Comment: Thank you-  NAPS2... I like it! The only "additional thing" is that the user has to accept a save as dialog. before, the file was created by dropping it in the folder. but in my opinion they should rename it afterwards... so this is a solution that fits almost perfectly for me !!

Print to PDF ist too many extra steps IMHO